# Create grids with arbitrary columns counts in different responsive layouts

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have an Rails app I am building with Foundation. I am having trouble figuring out how to display an arbitrary number of columns per row and keep it responsive in the small/medium/large layouts.

For example, lets say I have a model `Department` which has many `Employees`. I am trying to build the department page and display a list of the employees in the department. One department may have 10 employees. Another may have 6. It's arbitrary.

I want to do 4 columns in `large`, 2 columns in `medium` and 1 column in `small`. (See my wireframe below). However, the columns need to be wrapped in a `div.row`. This requirement means I have either of the following two situations:

- **Case #1** ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag3Ys/)) I have 2 elements per row and the `large` layout only gets 2 elements because it is getting cleared by the `.row`.
- **Case #2** ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffrod/YQ33R/1/)) I have 4 elements per row and the columns don't clear properly when in the 2-column, `medium` layout because there are 4 in a row.

This seems like it should be a pretty standard situation but I cant seem to figure it out. How do I do this? Is Foundation the wrong tool?

[image]

Comment: Look into something like Masonry.js (http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: I've seen masonry before. I'd prefer to exhaust all options with Foundation before I add another library. This seems like something Foundation should be able to handle.

Comment: Also, I dont necessarily care if the vertical alignment is micromanaged (a la masonry), as long as the floats are cleared properly.

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html

Comment: With that link, are you suggesting that I change the widths of the medium and large breakpoints? I'm not sure I see how that link addresses the question.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this question? I'm also looking for this!

Answer (score 0):

Media Queries and CSS might do the trick:

```
// medium 
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) and (max-width: 64em) {
  .row > div:nth-child(2) {clear: left;}
}
```

With 4 elements per row

http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/nthchild.html
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html